# Set Target Platform with Flutter Build

Tags: flutter, dart, github-actions, cicd

I'm setting up a CI pipeline for a Flutter app using Github Workflows.

For this, I want to build for each of the following platforms:

- Windows x64
- MacOS x64
- MacOS arm64
- Linux x64
- Android arm64

So, what I can't seem to do is work out how to determine whether to build for arm64 or x64 when running `flutter build macos` there doesn't seem to be any sort of `--target-platform` flag that I can use.

Surely this must be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter builds universal binaries when targeting macOS, so you can just build once and the output will run on both arm64 and x86_64 Mac machines.

If you still want separate builds for each architecture, you can specify which architecture to build for with the `FLUTTER_XCODE_ARCHS` environment variable. Set it to either `x86_64` or `arm64` depending on which architecture you want to build for.